# HTML View Postgresql TextArea render line breaks or paragraphs -python flask

Tags: python, html, postgresql

I have a TextAreaField where a user can write something, but when I render this TextArea in HTML the Text has no linebreaks. But in the DB it is saved correctly.

User Input before it is saved in the DB:

[image]

TextArea in DB:

[image]

How the text is rendered from the DB:

[image]

I am working with Flask WTForms and that is my form field:

```
infofeld = TextAreaField('Beschreibung')
```

That is the code where I render it. The Columns in the DB is named `"infofeld"`:

```
<p class="text"> {{ detail_room.infofeld }} </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text in db stored with just "\n" as symbol of new line. But html can show such text with new line with PRE tags: `<PRE>...</PRE>` . Or you can change \n to `<br>` or `<p>`

Comment: Thanks the <pre> tags are working fine, what is best practise in this case?

Comment: As variant you can store text as html with all possible formatting. Disadvantages - size & problems with searching.